# php Constant key value array

Tags: php

Is there any way to create array with key constants like mentioned below in php

```
class MysqlConstants
{
    const masterDb['HOST'] = "ip";
    const masterDb['user'] = "user";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use two constants?

Comment: Have a look on this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236771/how-to-create-const-arrays-of-instances-of-a-class-within-that-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible; class constants must be literals, not expressions. The closest alternative is static properties:

```
class MySqlConstants
{
    public static $masterDb = array('HOST' => "ip", 'user' => "user");
}
```

I personally don't like this approach because constants should be immutable. This would be a better approach:

```
class MySqlConstants
{
    private static $masterDb = array('HOST' => "ip", 'user' => "user");

    public final static function getMasterDb()
    {
        return self::$masterDb;
    }
}
```

Lastly you could just split up the constants:

```
class MySqlConstants
{
    const HOST = "ip";
    const user = "user";
}
```

Btw, storing configuration in code is not something I would recommended unless their application constants; it would be better to store connection settings, etc. in an ini file for instance, and use [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) to retrieve it.

Comment: ist showing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @SheldonCooper Fixed, it only worked for 5.4 with the `[]` notation :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also serialize your array and then put it into the constant:

```
# define constant, serialize array
define ("CRED", serialize (array ("host"=>"ip", "user"=>"user")));

# use it
$my_credential = unserialize (CRED);
```

Comment: This has to be the best answer to the question so far. But as far as a realistic implementation, I agree with Jack.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `define("MYSQL_HOST","ip");` in another php file called, lets say config.php so you can easily access it with `MYSQL_HOST` without calling instances of class or `global $masterDb` every time u want to use it.

Another advantage of having config.php is that you can easily modify common used variables.